# Правописание заимствованных слов

Tags: словообразование

Как правильно написать по-русски слово "бойфренд", "дресскод", слитно или через дефис?

Answer (score 4):

По словарю Лопатина: [дресс-код](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E4%F0%E5%F1%F1%EA%EE%E4&all=x), [бойфренд](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E1%EE%E9%F4%F0%E5%ED%E4).

Comment: Почему именно так? В чем разница? Если бой-баба нужно писать через дефис, то почему бойфренд слитно?

Comment: @Кирилла, хотя бы потому, что в языке откуда слова заимствованы "boyfriend" пишется в одно слово, а "dress code" - в два (ср. *Нью-Йорк, Санкт-Петербург, Улан-Батор*). Да и в русском бойфренд произносят с одним ударением, а дресс-код с двумя.

Бой-баба - это русской слово образованое по тому же принципу что и "мать-и-мачеха" или "казаки-разбойники". Сращение двух слов. У бой-бабы в отличии от бойфренда два ударных слога.